# Clogin errors Rancid

Tags: configuration

I have configured a hp switch on Rancid. i have no problems when am able to clogin and hlogin  into the switch.when i run the rancid and check my logs when i check my logs i get the following output. I also need to check my config files.where do i check that.kindly help me on this.

These are the outputs of my log files:

```
Trying to get all of the configs.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 1.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 2.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 3.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 4.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;
=====================================
Getting missed routers: round 5.
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.200: ibm
unknown router manufacturer for 10.2.0.13: hp1
10.2.0.13 clogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
10.2.0.13: missed cmd(s): show tech transceivers,show module,show config status,show system-information,show system information,show stack,show version,show flash,write term,show config files
10.2.0.13: End of run not found
;

cvs diff: Diffing .
cvs diff: Diffing configs
cvs commit: Examining .
cvs commit: Examining configs
/usr/local/rancid/bin/control_rancid: 503: /usr/local/rancid/bin/control_rancid: sendmail: not found

ending: Mon Feb 3 14:32:35 EST 2014
```